# Testing the number of concurrent connection node.js application can handle

Tags: node.js

I want to test how many concurrent connections a node.js application can handle. What is the best way to do this? I have an application in node.js ready. Which will be the best way to test its capacity?

Answer (score 1):

If your application is using HTTP, I recommend [Siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/).

Comment: I second siege. Works gerat for HTTP node.js apps.